# Query firebase database for single document

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, google-cloud-firestore, angular2-observables

I am creating a profile page where a user can edit their own details. I have a Cloud Firestore Database (not the Realtime DB). I am using Firebase authentication so when the user logs in I can find the UID. I have assigned this to each user in a document, which is stored in a collection called 'users'. I am trying to query this collection to find the user's details so I can display them/manipulate them, etc. I am querying with a condition that id = ...

I have tried different things in the map section of the observable, but, I often get type errors about cannot assign *something* to *something*...

This is an example of what my Cloud Firestore DB looks like, with each user having an ID stored as an attribute.

[image: firebase database]

User service:

```
  getUserByQuery(uid : string) : Observable<User> {
    this.userQuery = this.afs.collection('users', 
      (ref) => ref.where('id', '==', uid).limit(1)).snapshotChanges().
          pipe(
            map(action => {.... SOMETHING HERE ....}
          ));
        return this.userQuery;
      }
```

Profile component:

```
private observable : Observable<User>;
ngOnInit() {
    //Get ID from auth
    this.id = this.authService.authState;
    this.observable = this.usersService.getUserByQuery(this.id);
    this.subscription = this.observable.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

When I console log, I get the following:

[image: Output from console log]

Comment: Please include your complete errors. Also is this about firestore or the realtime database?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect these questions. It is a Cloud Firestore DB, not the realtime DB